# extracting a line of numerical values from text file in R

Tags: r, character, text-mining

**THE PROBLEM:** 
I need to extract numerical values from a text file and have the strings transformed to numeric values.

For example, in my text file:

Yada yada yada...

Base frequencies: 0.247 0.355 0.158 0.261

blah blah ...

alpha[0]: 0.466477 rates[0] ac ag at cg ct gt: 0.0987 2.4837 0.4734 0.4902 0.2713 1.0000

more words...
End of text file.

i need to pull out:
 base (a vector, which should be (0.247,0.355,0.158,0.261))
 alpha (a variable which should equal 0.466477)
 rates (a vector which should equal (0.0987, 2.4837, 0.4734, 0.4902))

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**

```
library(tm)
#Read in text file
myfile <- "RAxML_info.gtr1"
mdata <- readLines(my file)
cline <- grep("Base frequencies:",mdata,value=TRUE)
as.vector(gsub("Base frequencies: ", "", cline))
```

> > [1] "0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261 "

this is just treating as one string and I cannot get it to be a vector of numeric values.

Using RStudio and R version 3.3.1

Comment: Try with `?strsplit`

Comment: `as.numeric(strsplit("0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261 ", ' ')[[1]])` or `unlist(read.table(text = "0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261 "))`

Comment: Thanks this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @HubertL's comment, you can use `strsplit` to get from where you are to where you want to be:

```
line <- "0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261 "
line <- strsplit( line, split = " " )[[1]]
line <- as.numeric( line )

line
[1] 0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261
```

Comment: @nbas great! Since your question is resolved then, make sure to close it off by marking an answer as accepted. I see from your comments that more than one worked for you, so choose the one that helped the most. That way your question can help others with the same problem too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
output <- "0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261 " 
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(output, " ")))
[1] 0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `scan`

```
scan(text=output, what = numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
#[1] 0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261
```

#### data

```
output <- "0.247 0.335 0.158 0.261 "
```